# SVN commit of big file tree

Tags: svn, commit

We use SVN Repository TortoiseSVN 1.14.1 and VisualSVN server 4.3.4. 
We periodically save in the SVN very big FPGA projects (1.4-2 GB) with deep folders tree and many
many files.
I think to save one ZIP-file-form of such projects instead of the files' tree.
Reasons:

- We do not use separate files/folders from such projects and keep them in the SVN only for future restore "as is" in case of some theoretical need
- No any merge/modification for separate file(s) we did or will do for such projects.
- We need to reduce time for commit/checkout due to time of processing of thousand files is always much more then for one file.
- I suppose that such big file tree is potential for failures

My questions:

- Do this approach is correct (use ZIP instead of files' tree)?
- If YES, which type of compress is better to use: zip, 7Z, tar.gz etc?

Answer (score 0):

Version control system is a system meant to be used to keep control of different versions of the same file. If there are no changes to the file then there is very little sense in using the system.

But if you need to import several FPGA projects, and those projects have many identical files, then you should import it in plain source format only once (some base version), and after that branch from it for new projects. First import is long, but branches will be cheap (they cost almost 0 space). Do not import it again, always use branching, and all will be fine.

There are some things that you can do to improve the download speed. Upgrade both server and client to the latest version, use new technology called "sharding" (look it up), change the protocol from http: to svn:, change the compression level, use SSD as storage. More info [here](https://tylerayoung.com/2017/06/08/speeding-up-svn-checkout-for-large-repositories/).